# Hungary - Schengen Visa processing time from India

Tags: schengen, indian-citizens, hungary

Thirteen days ago, I applied in India for a Schengen visa for Hungary.

Since then, the status of my application has remained unchanged, saying 'application has been forwarded.'

Is the embassy supposed to answer within 15 days of application?

Would a delay mean that there could be a problem with my application?

Should I call the embassy if I don't get a response within 15 days?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the official VFS website for Hungary visa in India, normally the embassy makes a decision within 15 days after complete visa application submission. The days would be start counting when embassy had received an application from VFS. In this regard you Will have to look exactly in which date and day you submitted your application not the one you submitted at VFS global.

15 days they mentioned is an average processing time, however this could be more than 15 days and neither the VFS nor the embassy/consulate would answer anything regarding time frame. Whatever the decision been made, the embassy/consulate would notify first the administrative authority which is VFS .

Is there any problem with your visa application? NO

All the embassies/ consulates go through a technical procedure and sometimes the process could be lengthy, which doesn't necessarily means there is a flaw in your application.

As it is clearly mentioned that calls regarding the time assessment at visa section would not be answered. However they must have provided you an official VFS receipt and every day you can track your application on VFS global website.